# Cannot get first(where:​) to work with [NSDictionary]

Tags: swift

I have an array of NSDictionary's and I want to get a dictionary out of the array with a specific key "id". I tried to do the following but I get the error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSDictionary?'

Consider the following example of what I am trying to do:

```
let dictionaries: [NSDictionary] = [NSDictionary(dictionary: ["id": "123", "name": "the name"]),
                                    NSDictionary(dictionary: ["id": "456", "name": "the other name"])]
if let dictionary = dictionaries.first(where: { $0.objectForKey("id") == "123" }) {
    print(event.objectForKey("name") ?? "")
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but why `NSDictionary`? It's better to use Swift Type: Dictionary.

Comment: Good point, ex Objective-C developer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the result of `objectForKey` (`object(for:)` in Swift 3). With a `NSDictionary`, which has no types, the result is `Any?`. You cannot compare `Any?` with a `String`. A cast to `String` is then needed:

```
if let dictionary = dictionaries.first(where: { $0["id"] as? String == "123" }) {
   print(dictionary["name"] ?? "")
}
```

The error message does not make sense though.

You can avoid the problem completely if you use a Swift dictionary, or even better, parse your dictionaries into structs/classes and work only with your classes. Never use dictionaries to represent objects in your app outside of decoding/encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`:

```
 let dictionaries: [NSDictionary] = [NSDictionary(dictionary: ["id": "123", "name": "the name"]),NSDictionary(dictionary: ["id": "456", "name": "the other name"])] 
 let requested = dictionaries.filter{ $0.object(forKey: "id") as? String == "123" }
```

With `first`.

```
 let result = dictionaries.first(where: {$0.object(forKey: "id") as? String == "123"})
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, do you know why $0 is able to have .object(forKey:) called on it fine in .filter, but not when I use .first?

Comment: @jakedunc you can call .object(forKey: "id") in first as well because you are working with NSDictionary in both cases.

Comment: @jakedunc It's not the use of `filter` that solves the problem in this case, it's the downcast to `String` (as `object(forKey:)` returns `Any?`). However, as many people have already pointed out, you should be using a Swift `Dictionary`, which would eliminate the need for the cast, as you can *tell* the compiler that it only has `String` keys and values.

Comment: Better use an optional cast (if you insist on keeping the NSDictionary): `{ $0.object(forKey: "id") as? String == "123" }` – works with `first` and with `filter`.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was missing the cast, thanks everyone!